# How to make Unity call a method after creating an object instance but before it is injected anywhere

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using Unity for dependency injection. I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
public interface MyInterface { void MyMethod(); }
```

When building Unity container:

```
myContainer.RegisterType<MyInterface, MyConcreteType>();

myContainer.AddPostConstructor(x => (x as MyInterface)?.MyMethod());
```

Is it possible? Is there a better/more elegant way?

Comment: Is the method from the same class? then call it from the class constructor..

Comment: The problem is, there can be multiple classes implementing MyInterface, some may be added in the future. They may be resolved by their concrete types, not necesserily by MyInterface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way - register implementations via special factory and use it:

```
class Factory
{
    IUnityContainer _container;

    public Factory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Register<TType>() where TType : MyInterface
    {
        myContainer.RegisterType<MyInterface, TType>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
        {
            var result = c.Resolve<TType>();
            result.MyMethod();
            return result;
        }));
    }

    public MyInterface Get()
    {
        _container.Resolve<MyInterface>();
    }
}
```

...

```
public TestClass
{
    Factory _factory;
    public TestClass(Factory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _factory.Register<MyConcreteType>();
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var service = _factory.Get();
    }
}
```

So, all future implementations must be registered in the factory. But still there is no guarantee that method `MyMethod` will be implemented correct or implemented at all.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! As for the method, it must be implemented as it's declared by MyInterface. If a programmer leaves the implementing method empty, it's their concious decision (which may be correct in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somethig like this:

```
myContainer.RegisterType<MyInterface, MyConcreteType>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
{
    var result = c.Resolve<MyConcreteType>();
    result.MyMethod();
    return result;
}));
```

Comment: This would probably work, but just for one concrete type. I'd like to have the method called for all instances of any type implementing MyInterface, even if somebody added a new class implementing this.